# What C# collection should I use for this use case?

Tags: c#, .net, enums

http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/user/335389-sergio-tapia/

I'm the Helper group, currently there are other groups. I want to write all possible groups to a C# class or something and then in the future when other groups are created I'd just modify that "collection of groups".

My question is, what C# structure should I use for this use case?

**Edit: Changed the question and some of the body for clarity.**

Comment: What do you mean of effectively ?

Comment: I absolutely don't understand your question. Could you add an example? Why do you want to put the enumeration "on another file"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing enumerations is fraught, but can be done to a limited extent. Consider:

```
public enum SomeColors
{
  Black,
  blue,
  red
}
```

Code in another assembly compiled to use `SomeColors.blue` will break if we do:

```
public enum SomeColors
{
  Black,
  Green,
  blue,
  red
}
```

Because it will have the value `1` compiled into it, which is now the value of `SomeColors.Green` while `SomeColors.blue` is now `2`.

Also, if we were to change the first to have the same capitalisation throughout to:

```
public enum SomeColors
{
  Black,
  Blue,
  Red
}
```

Then running code would still work, but re-compiling would have compiler errors, as `SomeColors.Blue` would not work. Also, `Enum.Parse` would (in this case, depending on the case-sensitivity setting) work depending on which version of SomeColors was available to the running code.

However, adding values is not a breaking change. If we took the first and changed it to:

```
public enum SomeColors
{
  Black,
  blue,
  red,
  green
}
```

Then all existing code would be okay, but of course not know about `green` unless found with `Enum.Parse`.

So, if you are only going to add, and if you can depend upon nobody trying to `Enum.Parse` a string from a more recent version, then it'll work.

The same holds true of `const` values.

If you need to have values be changeable with versions, then you should use:

```
public static class SomeColors
{
  public static readonly int Black = 0;
  public static readonly int Blue = 1;
  public static readonly int Red = 2;
}
```

As these are not constants, but fields assigned statically, they will be used from the class rather than compiled-in, and changes to the class will change what is used. Further safety in some cases can be given by making them properties rather than fields; most notably in that if you may want to make the calculated properties in the future, it would be a breaking change if they are currently fields but not if they are already properties.

If you want the values to be dynamic at runtime, then you need a class with an indexer that takes a string and returns an integer.